# How to show that $E[\phi(X,Y)|G]=E[\phi(x,Y)]$ for all $x$?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

The question is, Given a probability space $(\Omega, F, P)$, a sigma field $G \subset F$, random variables $X,Y$ and a measurable function $\phi$ such that $X \in G$, $Y$ is independent with $G$ and $E[|\phi(X,Y)|] < \infty$. Then,

Show that $E[\phi(X,Y)|G]= g(X)$, where $g(x) = E[\phi(x,Y)]$ for all $x$.

I proved this result when $X,Y$ are independent. What is direction to prove this if independence condition is not given?

Comment: As $X$ is $G$-measurable (do you mean this with $X \in G$?) and $Y$ is $G$-independent, $X$ and $Y$ are independent.$\\$Moreover: What do you mean by for all $x$?

Comment: @martini yes $X$ is $G$- measurable means $X \in G$.

Comment: Did you mean something like this? $$E[\phi(X,Y)|G]=E[\phi(x,Y)]|_{x=X}$$

Comment: @BrianMoehring I corrected my question.

Comment: Note that this is not necessarily true merely under the assumption $X,Y$ are independent.  We need the stronger assumption that $X \in G$ and $Y$ is independent with $G$ (or something nearly as strong).  The assumptions here _are_ stronger than the assumption $X,Y$ are independent, however, as they imply $X,Y$ are independent.

Answer (score 0):

For functions of the product form $\phi(X,Y)=h(X)f(Y)$ the claim follows directly from $\mathbb E[f(Y)|{\cal G}]=\mathbb E[f(Y)]$ and $\mathbb E[h(X)|{\cal G}]= h(X)\,:$
$$
\mathbb E[h(X)f(Y)|{\cal G}]=h(X)E[f(Y)]
$$
which is obviously equal to $E[h(x)f(Y)]|_{x=X}\,.$ To extend this to all measurable $\phi$ with $\mathbb E[\phi(X,X)]<+\infty$ I would look at the [monotone class theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_class_theorem).