# Conditional expectations as functions

Tags: conditional-expectation

Consider the following conditional expectation:
$$
\mathbb{E}[f(X,Y,Z)\mid X,Y]
$$
I know that it can be written as $m(X,Y)$, where
$$
m(x,y)=\mathbb{E}[f(X,Y,Z)\mid X=x, Y=y].
$$
Is its section $y\mapsto m(X,y)$ equivalent to
$$
y\mapsto \mathbb{E}[f(X,y,Z)\mid X]?
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don´t think so. What is true is the following:

When $Z$ is independent of $X$ and $Y$ then by [this property of conditional expectations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4375419/how-to-show-that-e-phix-yg-e-phix-y-for-all-x/),
$$
\mathbb E[f(X,Y,Z)|X,Y]=\mathbb E[f(x,y,Z)]\Big|_{x=X,y=Y}\,.
$$
Likewise, when $X$ and $Z$ are independent of $Y$ then
$$
\mathbb E[f(X,Y,Z)|Y]=\mathbb E[f(X,y,Z)]\Big|_{y=Y}\,.
$$